# Custom myParseInt() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I have to develop custom myParseInt function in JavaScript which will take a string as a parameter and then return all integers in provided parameter with data type of number.
here is my code

```
'use strict';

function myParseInt (value) {
    let items = value.split('').map(Number);
    let myNumbers = [];
    items.forEach(function(item){
        if(typeof item === 'number' && !isNaN(item)) {
            myNumbers.push(item);
        }
    });
    return myNumbers.join('');
}
var result = myParseInt('sq12q12');
console.log(result, typeof result );
```

**Actual Output**

```
1212 string
```

**Desired Output**

```
1212 number
```

I am getting desired value but issue is with datatype. How can I do this with out using parseInt.

Here is Repl session for code testing https://repl.it/vPn/12

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a regular expression ? Like:
`+('sq12sq12'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));`
See https://repl.it/vPn/15

Comment: @ben using regular expression is a  interesting idea. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert before return:

```
 var n = Number(myNumbers.join(''));
 return n;
```

## EDIT

You can see here:
https://repl.it/vPn/14

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is supposed to return a string. You need to cast that string to a number.

Having said that, you can rewrite your function like this:

```
function myParseInt(value) {
    // strip all non-digit characters from string
    // cast the resulting string to a number
    return Number(value.replace(/\D/g, ""));
}
var result = myParseInt("sq12q12");
console.log(result, typeof result);
// 1212 number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match an integer using the regular expression `/[+-]?\d+/` (however, in this case, a leading `+` is superfluous so it can be shortened to `/-?\d+/`) which can then be converted to a number using a variety of methods:

- `+x`
- `x|0`
- `x*1`
- `parseInt(x,10)`
- `Number(x)`
- `y=0;x='-234';for(var i in x){if(0<x[i]&&x[i]<=9){y*=10;y+=+x[i];}}if(x[0]==='-')y=-y;`

You can then use it in a function like this:

```
function myParseInt( value ){
  return +value.match( /-?\d+/g ).join( '' );
}
```

However, if there is a negative integer that is not first in the list (i.e. `sq12sq-12` then then output is `NaN number` (which is probably valid since `12-12` is not a number). If we assume the question means Natural numbers (and not Integers) then we can use:

```
function myParseInt( value ){
  return +value.match( /\d+/g ).join( '' );
}
```

And the output is:

```
var v = myParseInt( "12sq-12" );
console.log( v, typeof v ); // "1212 number"
```

**Edit**

> take a string as a parameter and then return all integers in provided parameter with data type of number

I would have read that as returning an array of Integers each comprised of consecutive digits within the string rather than concatenating all the digits together to form a single Integer - in which case, it can be solved using:

```
function myParseInt( value ){
  return value.match( /[+-]?\d+/g ).map( Number );
}
```

Which outputs:

```
myParseInt( "1 +23 -45 6-78" );
// [1,23,-45,6,-78]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a a `return +myNumbers.join('');`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to do the string to integer/number conversion yourself, you could do something like this (but the other solutions are easier):

```
function myParseInt(stringValue) {
    function charToDigit(c) {
        return (
               c==="0"? 0 : 
               c==="1" ? 1 :
               c==="2" ? 2 :
               c==="3" ? 3 :
               c==="4" ? 4 :
               c==="5" ? 5 :
               c==="6" ? 6 :
               c==="7" ? 7 :
               c==="8" ? 8 :
               c==="9" ? 9 : NaN
        );
    }
    stringValue = stringValue.replace(/\D/g,''); //strip out letters
    var num = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<stringValue.length; i++) {
        num += charToDigit(stringValue[stringValue.length - (1 + i)]) * Math.pow(10, i);
    }
    return num;
}
```

But here is probably one of the shortest ways to do it:

```
function myParseInt(stringValue) {
    return +stringValue.replace(/\D/g,'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to iterate through the string backwards and get the integer value of the char. Then multiply the char with the current position in the number (1, 10, 100, ...).

To get the integer value of the char you can subtract the '0' char which represents the value of the '0' symbol in the ASCII table. By doing so you end up with a number from 0-9. If you get a value that is not between 0-9 you can simply skip it.

```
function parseIntCustom(toParse) {
    var out = 0;
    var factor = 1;
    for (var X = toParse.length - 1; X >= 0; X--) {
       var char = toParse.charAt(X) - '0';
       if(char >= 0 && char <= 9){
           out += char * factor;
           factor *= 10;
       }
    }
    return out;
}

console.log(parseIntCustom("123TEST123123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with arrays?, can do it faster using RegExp `+value.replace(/\D/g,'')`. Using arrays could also do it this way:

```js
var myParseInt = (value) => +[...value].filter(Number).join('')

console.log(myParseInt('sq12q12'))
```